# Unity unit testing - registering types

Tags: unit-testing, unity-container

I'm having a difficult time registering my types for Unity 2 in my unit tests.

Here's a snippet of the class under test:

```
public class SomeService : ISomeService
{
    private int SomeVar { get; set; }

    [Dependency]
    public ISessionManager SessionManager { get; set; }

    public SomeService()
    {
        SomeVar = SessionManager.Get<int>("SomeVar");
    }
}
```

Here's what I have in my MSTest ClassInitialize method:

```
private static ISomeService _someService;
private static IUnityContainer _unityContainer;
[ClassInitialize]
public static void MyClassInitialize(TestContext testContext)
{
    var mockSessionManager = new Mock<ISessionManager>();

    mockSessionManager.Setup(foo => foo.Get<int>(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(1);

    _unityContainer = new UnityContainer()
        .RegisterInstance(mockSessionManager.Object)
        .RegisterType<ISomeService, SomeService>(
            new InjectionProperty("SessionManager"));

    _someService = _unityContainer.Resolve<IAdditionalCoveragesService>();
}
```

For every test method that I have, when I debug and step into the constructor of SomeService, it says that SessionManager is null. What am I doing in wrong in trying to register my types in Unity?

Note - I am using Moq to set up a mock session manager that should be injected into SomeService.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's an injection property: the property is set after being created. To use SessionManager in the constructor you should use constructor injection:

```
public class SomeService : ISomeService
{
    private int SomeVar { get; set; }

    public ISessionManager SessionManager { get; private set; }

    public SomeService(ISessionManager sessionManager)
    {
        SessionManager = sessionManager;
        SomeVar = SessionManager.Get<int>("SomeVar");
    }
}
```

and:

```
_unityContainer = new UnityContainer()
        .RegisterInstance(mockSessionManager.Object)
        .RegisterType<ISomeService, SomeService>();
```

Comment: Right, but i'd rather not have to create a new constructor to set the SessionManager. Is it not possible to inject the property before the constructor?

Comment: How can set a property before an object exists? If you don't want to add a constructor, you can put your logic in the setter of SessionManager

Comment: Yes, your SessionManager will always be null in the constructor, period, DI container or not. Properties just don't work that way.